# How to align ImageView in Listview (Android)

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview

quick one I think:

I am failing to get my listView to align the embedded ImageView properly.

As you can see below, the images don't line up correctly (they are being affected by the amount of text in the neighbouring TextView):

[image: image issue]

Here is the offending xml file for the row item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="left">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flagIcon"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:src="@drawable/orange_flag"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_row_item_main_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/location_row_item_secondary_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_spec_button"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="60sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="@string/location_add_spec"
    android:onClick="myClickHandler"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try giving equal weight to the ImageView and LinearLayout ,..

Comment: No, doesn't work I'm afraid.  After some more fiddling I think it is because the imageView is being resized - is there a way to stop this I wonder..

Comment: remove android:layout_weight="0.05" Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Layout view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_live" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_live" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="left">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flagIcon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/orange_flag"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_row_item_main_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_row_item_secondary_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" 
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_spec_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/location_add_spec"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The main problem was caused by the width of the center vertical `LinearLayout`. Also weight of the `ImageView` was useless and it has some attributes used in `RelativeLayout`.

Note 1: Mind the difference between `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`.

Note 2: `sp` size unit is used for text sizes. From the docs:

> A dp is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to the physical
>   size of a pixel at 160 dpi. 
> An sp is the same base unit, but is scaled
>   by the user's preferred text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so
>   you should use this measurement unit when defining text size (but
>   never for layout sizes).