# Android: align items of a Listview

Tags: android, listview, alignment

I have a listview and I would like to have the following structure:

[link to example image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821152/how-to-align-imageview-in-listview-android)

I have several problems: the text is not aligned with the image, the right image disappears in some items, 2 lines are not show... I need help please. 
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/listview_naranja"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenListview"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoListviewNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoListviewTipo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textoListviewNombre"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenVisto"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenVisto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks

**EDIT:**

New code posted. My textoListviewNombre not alignTop with my thumbnail and my imagenVisto appears on my thumbnail

Comment: This will be implemented by creating custom listview

Comment: yes, i want a custom listview

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Layout view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_live" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play_live" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```